# Palabras muy frecuentes en el corpus que no aparecen en el diccionario de gensim

Tags: python

Estoy realizando un modelo lda en python y cuando creo el diccionario utilizando la librería de gensim no me aparecen palabras muy frecuentes en el corpus, no he aplicado todavía ningun filtro al diccionario. ¿Alquien sabe el motivo? ¿Es normal que no aparezcan las palabras más frecuentes en el diccionario?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Para mejorar las posiblidades de obtener respuesta deberías proporcionar más contexto a la pregunta. Algún enlace para ver el código o aprender qué es gensim, por ejemplo, o un ejemplo de palabra que crees que debería aparecer pero no aparece.

Comment: @abulafia No creo que sea buena idea motivar al usuario a poner enlaces al código. Los links se podrían caer. El código debe ir en la pregunta.

Comment: @DanteS. No me refería a código del usuario necesariamente, sino a código de ejemplo de uso de ese dataset. Quizás haya notebooks públicos en github, pero sí, coincido en que es preferible código incluido en la pregunta, si bien este no debería ser excesivamente largo. Un "Minimal Working Example", vamos.

Comment: @abulafia Ahhh entiendo, en ese caso no dije nada!